# combining results from multiple rxjs observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have an autocomplete input which, as the user types, fetches data from multiple endpoints, such as:

```
//service call to fetch data and return as single observable
getAutocompleteSuggestions() {
    const subs$ = [
        this.http.get(endpoint1),
        this.http.get(endpoint2),
        this.http.get(endpoint3)
    ];

    return Observable.forkJoin(...subs$);
}
```

Each of these endpoints returns data of the form:

```
{ data: [], status: xyz }
```

I would like to use switchmap as I want to only show results from the final call, and have tried the following:

```
   this.getAutocompleteSuggestions(query)
          .switchMap(res => {
             return res.data;
           })
          .subscribe((results: any) => {
            this.results = results;
          });
```

But the 'res' in the switchmap is an array, any idea how results can contain a single array containing the data from the response of any number of observables?

Comment: That's what forkJoin does.  It combines the results into a single array.  Maybe I don't understand your question though... can you clarify?

Comment: forkjoin produces a result which is an array, so i want to flatten that array, transform it (such as through map()) and cancel previous requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you want, but I think this is it:

```
$filter: Subject<string> = new Subject(); //I guess we have some value to filter by??
```

Push a value to the subject:

```
this.$filter.next(myNewValue);
```

In the constructor or init:

```
this.$filter
   .switchMap(filterValue => { //Get the values when filter changes
       subs$ = [
         this.http.get(endpoint1 + filterValue),
         this.http.get(endpoint2 + filterValue),
         this.http.get(endpoint3 + filterValue)
       ];

       return Observable.forkJoin(...subs$);
   })
   .map(results => { //now map you array which contains the results
      let finalResult = [];
      results.forEach(result => {
          finalResult = finalResult.concat(result.data)
      })
      return final;
   })
   .subscribe(); //Do with it what you want
```

The entire steam will be executed again when we put a new value into our subject. SwitchMap will cancel all ready requests if there are any.

Comment: Interesting, so the forkjoin is inside the switchMap? is it possible to chain it so the switchmap takes the response of my requests/observables?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros at that point it will be too late since `switchMap` won't be able to cancel those observables.

Comment: Not cancel, just emit the last result

Comment: I think maybe I'm confused around the chaining element, I'm seeing examples such as:
Rx.Observable.of('some_url')
  .switchMap(url => this.http.get(url)), so maybe i have to make a blank observable and chain the switchmap to that can call the service in there?

Comment: SwitchMap can change the observable steam from a value to a new value which comes from another stream. In that small example: string to response from a new http stream. This will only work once because Observable.of will never emit multiple values. If you want another result you need to create and call the stream again. In you question the value comes from a autocomplete. This value changes so we put it in a subject. The difference between Observable.of and the subject is the subject can emit more than once. Since the subject emits multiple values we use switchmap to cancel previous request.

Comment: So I used your answer to refactor my code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191962/convert-rjxs-map-and-flatten-to-flatmap for an updated question

Answer (score 1):

I have used something similar to this, and worked well so far:

```
        let endpoint1 = this.http.get(endpoint1);
        let endpoint2 = this.http.get(endpoint2);
        let endpoint3 = this.http.get(endpoint3);

        forkJoin([endpoint1, endpoint2, endpoint3])
          .subscribe(
            results => {
              const endpoint1Result = results[0].map(data => data);
              const endpoint2Result = results[1].map(data => data);
              const endpoint3Result = results[2].map(data => data);

              this.results = [...endpoint1Result, ...endpoint2Result, ...endpoint3Result];
            },
            error => {
              console.error(error);
            }
          );
```

Obviously is a pretty simple example, you'll be able to handle better the results to suit your needs.

Comment: Yea I know I can do this,  but it doesn't use switchMap, thanks though