# convert rjxs map and flatten/reduce to flatMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I believe the following code can be refactored using a flatMap but I cant seem to get it working as desired.

I understand flatMap essentially maps and then flattens, which is perfect for me as I'm using forkJoin so get an array of responses back from getAutocompleteSuggestions().

I want a single array of results upon subscription (which is what the code below produces), but changing the top level map to flatMap sends multiple single objects to the subscription. How can this code be better written with flatMap()?

```
   const $resultsObservable: Observable<any> = Observable.of(query)
          .switchMap(q => this.getAutocompleteSuggestions(q))
          //tried changing the below to flatMap()
          .map(res => { 
            return res.map(resp => {
              const content = resp.content;
              content.map(result => this.someMethod(result));
              return content;
            })
            .reduce((flatArr, subArray) => flatArr.concat(subArray), []);
          });



  getAutocompleteSuggestions(query: string): Observable<any> {
    const subs$ = [];
    //... add some observables to $subs
    return Observable.forkJoin(...subs$);
  }
```

Comment: The `content.map(…)` line in there is either a bug or unclear. Since you don't use its result, `someMethod` is executed, but is not the result returned in the observable chain. If that's intended, you should run it in a side effect (`do`) on observable level and using `forEach` on the array level. `map` (on both levels) is there to map data, not to execute side effects.

Comment: resp.content is an array, so im transforming that and then returning it, essentially discarding everything else in resp, and transforming the data i need to

Comment: `map` doesn't modify an array in-place.

Comment: Sure, but the variables (result) being passed in are passed by reference, objects that are modified and stay modified in the (passed by reference) array

Comment: Then you should use `forEach`. `map` is not for side effects. The code may work, it's just badly designed and breaks the principle of least surprise.

Comment: but I want the value of content to replace each res. returning to foreach doesnt manipulate the data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a bit of confusion between the RxJS `flatMap` and the Array prototype method `flatMap`. Note that the purpose of the RxJS flatMap is not to flatten arrays that are the subjects of the stream, but rather to flatten a stream of Obervables into a single observables. See this SO post:

[Why do we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-do-we-need-to-use-flatmap)

> ... Basically if Observable denotes an observable object which pushes values of type T, then flatMap takes a function of type T' -> Observable as its argument, and returns Observable. map takes a function of type T' -> T and returns Observable.

If you want your code to be a bit cleaner, you could use the `myArray.flatMap` method. Here's a potential answer to your question with the Array `flatMap` method:

```js
const $resultsObservable: Observable<any> = Observable.of(query)
  .switchMap(q => this.getAutocompleteSuggestions(q))
  // Flatmap on the array here because response is an array of arrays.
  // The RxJS flatMap does not deal with flattening arrays
  .map(res => res.flatMap(resp => {
    const content = resp.content;
    content.map(result => this.someMethod(result));
    return content;
  }));

getAutocompleteSuggestions(query: string): Observable < any > {
  const subs$ = [];
  //... add some observables to $subs
  return Observable.forkJoin(...subs$);
}
```

Comment: On this line:
  .map(res => res.flatMap(resp => {
res is an array, so I get an error, "res.flatMap is not a function"

Comment: Apologies, the `flatMap` method is not part of the javascript spec - it has only been proposed and is [not supported by any browsers yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Looks like you may have to use a combination of `map` and a flatten method of your own. Or you could try using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).